# How do you set a variable equal to the value returned by a function in python

Tags: python, sprite, pygame

I'm trying to design a system that will allow me to move sprites to the cursor position when clicked, similar to RuneScape, where the player will move to the position of the mouse click on the screen. Here is my code below:

```
    for event in pygame.event.get ():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit ()
        sys.exit (0)

    elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_UP:
            Shrin_y -= 5
        elif event.key == K_LEFT:
            Shrin_x -= 5
        elif event.key == K_RIGHT:  
            Shrin_x += 5 
        elif event.key == K_DOWN:   
            Shrin_y += 5 
    elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        (Shrin_x, Shrin_y) = pygame.mouse.get_pos
        print pygame.mouse.get_pos

Surface.blit (Shrin, (Shrin_x, Shrin_y))

pygame.display.update ()
```

Note: Shrin is just the name of the sprite; if it pleases you, just replace all instances of Shrin in the code with 'sprite'.

So how do you store the value RETURNED by `pygame.mouse.get_pos` in `(Shrin_x, Shrin_y)`?

Comment: @Levon: I think he's missing `()`..

Comment: @DSM Ah yes .. he needs `pygame.mouse.get_pos()`

Comment: @DSM .. just go ahead and plop it down as an answer .. better you than someone else who wanders by and skips the solution in the comments :-)

Comment: @DSM -- yeah, I was almost that person who skipped the solution in the comments until I decided to read the comments before posting ...

Answer (score 6):

```
(Shrin_x, Shrin_y) = pygame.mouse.get_pos
```

This line should be giving you an error, because it is trying to unpack a single value (a function or method object) to two variables. What you want is:

```
(Shrin_x, Shrin_y) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

The difference is that the `()` is the operator which calls the callable object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [`pygame.mouse.get_pos`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pos).  The way you have it in your code you are just looking at the method.  So change just change one line:

```
(Shrin_x, Shrin_y) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```